# Font is not displayed correctly in different zooms and display sizes

Tags: css, fonts, sass, font-size

I'm using: `font-family: "Helvetica LT Bold",sans-serif;` font in my page

```
@font-face {
font-family: "Helvetica LT";
src: url("/assets/fonts/HelveticaLTStd-Roman.ttf") format("ttf"),
     url("/assets/fonts/HelveticaLTStd-Roman.woff") format("woff"),
     url("/assets/fonts/HelveticaLTStd-Roman.woff") format("otf");
font-weight: normal;
font-style:  normal;
```

}

```
@font-face {
font-family: "Helvetica LT Bold";
src: url("/assets/fonts/HelveticaLTStd-Bold.ttf") format("ttf"),
     url("/assets/fonts/HelveticaLTStd-Bold.woff") format("woff"),
     url("/assets/fonts/HelveticaLTStd-Bold.otf") format("otf");
font-weight: lighter;
font-style:  normal;
```

}

and in different zooms the text looks crooked and is displayed incorrectly. 
For example, it works with chrome on 100%, 125% , but doesn't with 75%, 80% etc, 
Edge doesn't work a 100%. Is it possible to correct this issue somehow without changing to another font?
Here;s's an example:
[image]

you can see the letters are dispalyed weirdly

Comment: Some fonts just don't display well in all font sizes. If changing the font family is not an option, there's not much you can do. CSS does not have a way to check if a font size will come out readable or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Helvetica LT isn't a web-safe font.

I had this issue a few years ago and eventually had to switch to a new font to stop this issue.

For help choosing a web safe font try this:

https://www.cssfontstack.com/